# Bitcoin Core download crashed

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

I was adding a new drive to my PC when Bitcoin Core download crashed ..no idea why, anyway I cannot reboot and have no access now, I was in the middle of slowly downloading the blockchain to get started on my node. Advice please, I do not want to start the slow process of downloading again if possible. Be gentle I am a complete newbie. Cheers Q

Comment: Welcome to bitcoin.stackexchange.com. Can you clarify exactly what you need help with? downloading software? initial blockchain download? reinstalling an operating system on a PC that won't start? Recovering data from a dead hard disk?

Answer (score 1):

In the same folder as your wallet.dat file should be a debug.log file.
it is a log file that could reveal why your instance crashed.
If you post that file, or read it yourself (there is no sensitive info in log files AFAIK) then we can perhaps find the answer.